# Text with fixed size (overriding browser zoom functionality)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set a fixed size to a text element so it won't grow bigger when user zooms in with browser built in zoom function (ctrl and +)

I've tried with

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
-ms-text-size-adjust: none;
-moz-text-size-adjust: none;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

but I've had no luck.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That makes no sense. The font doesn't actually resizes. You're just zooming the page. Font still has the same size.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't. If a user decides he/she wishes to font to be bigger by zooming in, your website should comply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the comments stating that this is not possible are wrong. You *can* prevent this, using viewport, for example:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

As an aside, I wouldn't recommend this approach. I think you've got lost somewhere along the way here, this is not responsive design.

Please also be aware of compatibility issues with `vh`, `vw` and `vmin`:

http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: And how does this do what the OP asked? Your link allows me to zoom in and out. Exactly what the OP doesn't want to happen. `vh`, `vw` and `vmin` are all relative sizes based on the viewport size, but they don't prevent scaling.

Comment: I normally have my browser zoom settings set to "Zoom text only", which makes this example not work as intended (my font grows larger and smaller as I zoom in/out).

Comment: @ScottMarcus - you've misunderstood what the OP has asked for.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ It's pretty clear what the OP wants... to disable CTRL + and CTRL - to scale text on a page. Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm developing a little internal site at my company and I don't need responsiveness, I just need it to work. Thank you again

Comment: @ScottMarcus - evidently, that's not at all what the OP meant. You misread his question. He doesn't want to disable that at all, he wants to the text to stop responding to it.

Comment: @AndreaConte - not a problem.

Comment: That's exact what I said and your code doesn't do that.

Comment: In OP's words, this is "exactly" what he was looking for. I don't know how else to address this question, I'm afraid.